# Microsoft Azure Cloud service management API fails with 401: Unauthorized error?

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-management-api

We are integrating the `Role Assignments - List` API from Microsoft Azure Cloud Management APIs, Link to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/list#errordetail

We have done all of the configs mentioned:

- Registered a multi-tenant web app with Azure Active Directory for OAuth using `App Registrations` option,
- Also enabled the `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` scope under Azure Service Management
- Same scope is requested by the web app

So far OAuth succeeds but the access token received when used to call an API `GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2015-07-01` it fails with 401 Unauthorized error. I have replaced the `subscriptionId` with the appropriate value while making actual call.

I looked at the details of access token using `https://jwt.io/` and the `scp` element only seems to have `"scp": "User.Read"` scope, Missing the `user_impersonation`. Though the AUTH dialog from Microsoft login service shows clearly the requested `user_impersonation` grant. The user account I am using for the OAuth has access to the given azure subscription.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to add `scope` with `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` when requesting for an access token.

Test using [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) in browser:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<your-app-id>
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=<your-redirect_uri>
&scope=https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

[image]

**Note:** If you use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), change `scope` to `https://management.azure.com/.default`.

Comment: I removed the `User.Read` permission & only kept `https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation` permission then it started working without 401, Thanks